# Google Analytics for Mobile - Showing pageviews equal to Unique Visitors on live server

Tags: google-analytics, pageviews

I implemented google analytics with image tracking method to my mobile website. When I browse from my local server, google tracking is working fine and I found difference b/w page views and unique visitors. But when I browse in production server google tracking shows page views and unique visitors as same count. Below are the details of production server. Please suggest me about this.

Server Details:

OS: Ubuntu 10.04.2
Apache/2.2.14
PHP 5.3.2-1
Memcache 1.4.2
NFS 3
Rysnc 3.0.7
Varnish 2.1

Comment: not quite sure what you are asking here.

Comment: Please specify your question with more details: that is not clear what you're asking about.

Comment: I have implemented google analytics in the mobile website, to track the visitor views while navigating the  site pages. Generally when the visitor navigates the page ; in google analytics it will show the user count when navigating the webiste , the visitor count is increased when navigating the inner pages with same domain and same visitor , i.e. visitor count is getting increased by navigating each page in the mobile site... how to eliminate the increase the user count in this scenario when implemented in the production server

Comment: requirement is visitor count should not increase when the visitor navigating the inner pages of the site when the domain is same